# Calling Async Task present in other fragment from my fragment

Tags: android, asynchronous, fragment

I am calling a Async task present in other fragment on check box listener from some other fragment customview. Here is my code:

```
     OnCheckedChangeListener myChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                int checkedRow = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                int itemid = fetchedNewPick.get(checkedRow).getItemTypeId();
                int actionid = fetchedNewPick.get(checkedRow).getItemActionId();
                String serial = fetchedNewPick.get(checkedRow).getItemSerial();
                String itemRemark = fetchedNewPick.get(checkedRow).getItemRemark();
                Log.i("values", itemid+" " +actionid +" " + serial + itemRemark);

        "I want myAsyc called here"
                if(postStatus.contains("Success")){
                    dbController.deleteNewPickStatus(context, serial);
                    Setting_Fragment.updateArraylist(checkedRow);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                }
            }
        };
```

I tried to write something like this:
              new MyAsyc(context).execute();
But didn't work.

Comment: I think that the asynctask is an inner class of your fragment and you are trying to call it from a class in another file have a look at this and you will fiqure out how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: I have nothing to do with static..neither I want my asyntask to be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use event bus for communicating between fragments with [Square Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) or [Greenrobot Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) would be the choices.

Comment: I am using square otto please check this link of sample usage http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: google recommends not to use library that use dependency injection like butterknife and robojuice